# Img tag with image from Amazon S3 not working

Tags: html, image, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, src

I saved an image to my bucket and the url works. https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/aaronstestbucketpnw/Abraham-lincoln-quote-internet-hoax-fake.jpeg.  I am having an issue adding it to an img tag.

```
<img src="url(https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/aaronstestbucketpnw/Abraham-lincoln-quote-internet-hoax-fake.jpeg)" alt="not working">
```

Here is jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/aaronmk2/98L9retf/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use:

```
<img src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/aaronstestbucketpnw/Abraham-lincoln-quote-internet-hoax-fake.jpeg" alt="not working">
```

Comment: When I do this, I get a Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) error (in the inspector) - apparently, Chrome prevents linking to img sources on other websites? Cursory searches brought me here (https://zyst.io/how-to-fix-aws-s3-chrome-and-safari-cors-on-images) but I don't know how to apply this.